# Unable to switch to windows popup using selenium webdriver when there is no active windows user session

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, popupwindow

Unable to switch to windows popup using selenium webdriver when there is no active windows user session.

I have test case where we invoke windows windows print dialog from our application and we cancel the print dailog. i have used autoit and robot to handle windows popup.Both works fine on my local dev machine.

But when i run the same set of test cases through jenkins on a AWS server the test case fails after invoking the print dialog where there is no active user session.
The code works when i login and run the test cases but when i logout the test cases fail.